# Android Encrypt video file with Facebook conceal library

Tags: android, facebook, encryption

I want to encrypt video files stored in SD card

> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

I have found that Facebook conceal is good for encrypting large files. I have followed this tutorial [Make fast cryptographic operations on Android with Conceal](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/make-fast-cryptographic-operations-on-android-with-conceal/)

Here is what i have done up to now.

Encryption method

```
  public void encodeAndSaveFile(File videoFile, String path) { 

    try {
        final byte[] encrypt = new byte[(int) videoFile.length()];
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory, "en1");



        Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this), new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(mypath));
        OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                fileStream, new Entity("Passwordd"));
        outputStream.write(encrypt);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"Encrypted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Decryption method

```
    private void decodeFile(String filename,String path) { 

    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
            new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
   File directory = cw.getDir(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(directory, filename);

    try {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(fileStream,
                new Entity("Password"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"Decrypted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

But this code throwing following error at the run time

> java.lang.illegalArgumentException: File contains a path separator

Then i have changed "mypath: variable of  encodeAndSaveFile to this

```
 File mypath = new File(directory, "en1");
```

and "file" variable of decodeFile to this

```
File file = new File(directory, filename);
```

Then no errors but. Encryption is not happening. Please help to solve this or suggest correct method for video encryption with conceal lib.